# Jquery menu array opening ul in wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, menu, submenu

I'm creating Jquery menu items from an array

```
(function ($) {
var menu = [{
    title: "Home",
    href: "/"
}, {
    title: "Item 1",
    href: "/item2",
    items: [{
        title: "Sub",
        href: "/sub"
    }, {
        title: "Sub",
        href: "/sub"
    }]
}, {
    title: "Item 2",
    href: "/item2",
    items: [{
        title: "sub2",
        href: "/sub2"
    }, {
        title: "sub2",
        href: "/sub2",
        items: [{
            title: "sub3",
            href: "/sub3"
        }, {
            title: "Sub3",
            href: "/sub3"
        }, {
            title: "sub3",
            href: "/sub3"
        }, {
            title: "sub3",
            href: "/sub3"
        }]
    }, {
        title: "Item 3",
        href: "/item3"
    }]
}, {
    title: "Item 4",
    href: "/item4"
}];

$('nav').append(globalMenu(menu));

function globalMenu(el){
    console.log(el)
    var ul = $('<ul>')

    $.each(el, function(){
        var li = $('<li>')
        li.append($('<a>', {text : this.title, href : this.href}));           
        ul.append(li)
        if(this.items) li.after(globalMenu(this.items)); 
    })

    return ul;
}

}(jQuery));
```

The problem is that it's attaching the children of the UL wrong. For example the child ULs are sitting after the closing  of the parent like so:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/item2">Item 1</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/sub">Sub</a></li>
      <li><a href="/sub">Sub</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="/item2">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

It child ULs should be sitting within the the  of the parent item like so:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/item2">Item 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/sub">Sub</a></li>
          <li><a href="/sub">Sub</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><!-- close parent LI here -->
    <li><a href="/item2">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7Fcm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `li.after` use `li.append`

http://jsfiddle.net/T7Fcm/1/